# Rewrite nested Navigator 2.0 example using provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am looking to do a rewrite [of the official example for writing a nested navigator with bottom navigation](https://gist.github.com/johnpryan/bbca91e23bbb4d39247fa922533be7c9). Specifically, I want to write another implementation using provider for lifting up state, instead of passing a callback down to the page like it is happening here with ˋhandleBookTappedˋ.

**Q: How to use Provider to pass down BookAppState to the pages, while properly updating both outer and inner navigators without loosing state of the tabs.**

```
class InnerRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate<BookRoutePath>
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin<BookRoutePath> {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  BooksAppState get appState => _appState;
  BooksAppState _appState;
  set appState(BooksAppState value) {
    if (value == _appState) {
      return;
    }
    _appState = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  InnerRouterDelegate(this._appState);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      pages: [
        if (appState.selectedIndex == 0) ...[
          FadeAnimationPage(
            child: BooksListScreen(
              books: appState.books,
              onTapped: _handleBookTapped,
            ),
            key: ValueKey('BooksListPage'),
          ),
          if (appState.selectedBook != null)
            MaterialPage(
              key: ValueKey(appState.selectedBook),
              child: BookDetailsScreen(book: appState.selectedBook),
            ),
        ] else
          FadeAnimationPage(
            child: SettingsScreen(),
            key: ValueKey('SettingsPage'),
          ),
      ],
      onPopPage: (route, result) {
        appState.selectedBook = null;
        notifyListeners();
        return route.didPop(result);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(BookRoutePath path) async {
    // This is not required for inner router delegate because it does not
    // parse route
    assert(false);
  }

  void _handleBookTapped(Book book) {
    appState.selectedBook = book;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: @damian-k-bast Did you figure out how to update both outer and inner delegates? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

1. Add `MultiProvider` on your App (as your probably will use more than one).

```
    Future<void> main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    
      runApp(
        /// Providers are above [MyApp] instead of inside it, so that tests
        /// can use [MyApp] while mocking the providers
        MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => MyAppState()),
            //ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Counter()),
          ],
          child: RootRouter(),
        ),
      );
    
    }
```

2. Òn your `InnerRouterDelegate` use `.watch` to capture your index change inside the build.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var idx = context.watch<MyAppState>().selectedBottomNavIndex;
    return Navigator(
...
```

3. On your `bottomNavigationBar` replace `appState.` by `context.watch<MyAppState>().` (note that I am using enum for index, slightly different from the official example)

```
bottomNavigationBar:
        BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          items: BottomNavigationBarItems.items(),
          currentIndex: context.watch<MyAppState>().selectedBottomNavIndex.index,
          //currentIndex: appState.selectedBottomNavIndex.index, //replace
          onTap: (newIndex) {
            context.read<MyAppState>().selectedBottomNavIndex= NavItem.values[newIndex];
            //appState.selectedBottomNavIndex = NavItem.values[newIndex]; //replace
          },
        ),
```

This will make it work with Mobile. There is a lot of web stuff that needs to be updated too, and code cleaned/removed. `appState` variable becomes obsolete.

Comment: This works fine however there might be some [problems](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/760) which happens when you modify `appState` inside `setNewRoutePath` method while build happens which is quite common since `RouterDelegate` is subscribed to `AppState` in order to notify Router about changes. I found [two solutions](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/760#issuecomment-1158999451).